# Calculate area by given x and y Cartesian Point and radius in meter

Tags: java

How to calculate the area of radius by given latitude and longitude and radius?
Do we have any library in java to calculate this?

Comment: if you mean to calculate area of circle, then there is no need for latitude and longitude, but only radius is needed

Comment: Are you supposed to take the curvature of the Earth into account?

Comment: @eparvan Yes, calculate area of circle. How it will be possible to calculate without latitude and longitude?

Comment: @AnandKhatri it doesn't matter where the center of the circle is, the area of a circle depends only on its radius

Comment: @eparvan Agree, but here I have a big land from that Cartesian Point specifying a center point along the x & y plane.
From that two Cartesian point and radius, I need to calculate the area.

Comment: @AnandKhatri you mean you have two points {0,0} - center and {x,y} - point on the edge of circle and need to get area ?

Comment: @eparvan No, I have only one center point (x,y) and radius values, from this value I want to calculate area.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do:

```
double area = Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2)
```

I don't know how you need x and y for calculating the area..

Comment: Here, x and y are Cartesian Point specifying a center point along the x & y plane.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you need the full circle area:

> Math.pow(radius, 2) * Math.PI.

If you need the sector then it is something like:

> Math.pow(radius, 2) * Math.PI * (angle/360).

More here: [Area of a sector of a circle](https://www.mathopenref.com/arcsectorarea.html)

Now, if you some points,  it is

> double thetaAngle = atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180 / PI.

You can find the angle:[Angle between two points](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/318640-how-to-get-angle-between-two-points/)